# Div scroll with fixed steps like the select element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make a div to mimick the select-element in some ways but that also allow me to style and layout each item/option in any way I like.

One behaviour I'm trying to copy is the scrolling which is in fixed steps with the select-element.

How can I get this behaviour for a div-element (with any number of child-divs)?

(The child-div height is the same for every element)

The scrollbar should never be able to be put in a non multiple position of the child-div height.

**UPDATE**

This is the solution I came up with:

```
var scroller;
var itemHeight = 300;
function init(){
 scroller = document.getElementById('scrollDiv');
 scroller.onscroll = fixedScroll;
 scroller.onmousewheel = mousewheel;
 scroller.onkeydown = keydown;
}
function fixedScroll(e){
    e.target.scrollTop = Math.round(e.target.scrollTop / itemHeight) * itemHeight;
}
function mousewheel(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var sign = e.wheelDelta > 0 ? -1 : 1;
    e.target.scrollTop += sign * itemHeight;
}
function keydown(e){
    var sign = 0;
    if (e.keyCode === 40) sign = 1;
    else if (e.keyCode === 38) sign = -1;
    e.target.scrollTop += sign * itemHeight;
}
init();
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/4tj6r/61/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

**EDIT** Ah, it called upon itself once changing the scroll position so it ended up breaking the whole thing. This should do.

[And a DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4tj6r/59/)

```
var delta;
var scroller;
function init(){
 scroller = document.getElementById('scrollDiv');
 scroller.onscroll = fixedScroll;
 delta = scroller.scrollTop;
}
function fixedScroll(e){
 if(delta < e.target.scrollTop)
  e.target.scrollTop = delta + 100;
 if(delta > e.target.scrollTop)
  e.target.scrollTop = delta - 100;
 delta = e.target.scrollTop;
}

<body onload="init();">
<div id="scrollDiv" style="overflow:auto;height:100px;"></div>
```

Comment: Works well when scrolling with wheel and keyboard but when moving the scrollbar with the mouse (Chrome) I get a very jittery motion.

Comment: But I get the picture... I can figure this out now =) Thanks anyway

Comment: Yeah, the onscroll event happens -after- the scrolling, so it moves to a smoothed position, then aligns. This will lead to continuous tries to move to a smoothed position. You will have to supply your own scrollbar or do the changes before the scroll occurs and then prevent the actual scroll event. But the arrows work as well, so you could hide the scroll bar and just leave the arrow buttons.